# Microphone options greyed out

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-online

The options for listening to other people is fine. I can adjust the settings on that no problem. The problem is when I try to adjust any of my microphone settings or even try to enable the microphone. The settings are just greyed out. I can't do anything to my microphone settings.

My headset is the HyperX Cloud. I already updated audio drivers and that didn't help. It works on Skype and Teamspeak.

Edit: I forgot to mention I can't get Ventrilo to work. When I hit the setup button in Vent it gives me the "No mixers are available" error.  It does work in Skype and Teamspeak. I also did check my Steam settings and Steam can detect my mic and it works.                                                                                   ****I fixed the Vent issue I switched to 32bit version instead. GTA still having issues though.

I sent in a support ticket to Rockstar and they have yet to figure this issue out. Last response from them was May 18th 2015. I can see why none of you can help at all with this if they can't even figure it out.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct settings in steam.

Comment: Just checked the settings it works in there no problem it can detect it.